# Display data on UI from XML in project iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml

I need to know that i have a XML file, in my project I have some data in it.
How can i display that data in TableView, Tutorials given on internet serve the purpose to display XML data that is through some URL, i just want to display from my local file in project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Objective-C, am I correct?

Have you tried using NSXMLParser. I would assume you would be able to just use the contents of the file in your project and parse it with NSXMLParser.

You might want to have a look at this [NSXMLParser example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example)

Comment: yes i am using objective C, but i don't know the proper procedure to do that i need some code with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
      NSString *xmlFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TesingSampleXml" ofType:@"xml"];

      NSString *xmlString=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];

      NSData* xmlData=[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];

      [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

      [xmlParser parse];
```

Now Parse the data using the delegates of the NSXMLParserDelegates and then reload the tableview.

Comment: i do not understand how the data would come here, i am using pathForResource and i gave the path of my xml file there but still its not working ... kindly help me in giving complete understanding

Comment: try to NSLog(@"%@",xmlString); it will show your complete xml File

Comment: After that i have converted it into NSData type and loaded the NSXMLParser instance with it.

Comment: Check your xml file is inside the resource folder.

Comment: NSString *xmlFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"/Users/apple/Downloads/XML/Books.xml" ofType:@"xml"];
NSLog(@"file path is %@",xmlFilePath);
NSString *xmlString=[[NSStringalloc]initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
NSLog(@"file path is %@",xmlString);

Comment: the code u sent is ok this is my modified code have a look 


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
 
 //
NSString *xmlFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Users/apple/Downloads/XML/Books.xml" ofType:@"xml"];
NSString *xmlString=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
NSLog(@"file path is %@",xmlString);
NSData* xmlData=[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
XMLParser *xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
[xmlParser parse];
}

Comment: drop the xml in resource folder then only give the filename inside the pathforresource

Answer (score 0):

Best XML Parser tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 0):

To display data from xml file you need to parse the xml file. To parse file you can use any parser like  - NSXMLParser, tbxml and so on

**I recommend TBXML ** it is fast and light

[go through this link for more details](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)

Comment: but i don't know the proper procedure to do that i need some code with explanation.