# GDataXml Parsing Issues in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, gdataxml

here this is below the code i need to parse the section   and Company             Sub  data Using GDataXml in iOS.

```
-<MainList>
    <FirstMessage>Right</FirstMessage>
    <SecondMessage>Wrong</SecondMessage>
    <Status>0</Status>
   -<CompanyList>
     -<Company>
         <Address1>12447 Hedges Run Drive</Address1>
         <Address2>#B-1 </Address2>
         <City>Lake Ridge</City> 
         <CompanyName>Starbucks</CompanyName>
         <CreatedBy>example@example.com</CreatedBy>
     -</Company>
      -<Company>
         <Address1>12447 Hedges Run Drive</Address1>
         <Address2>#B-1 </Address2>
         <City>Lake Ridge</City>
         <CompanyName>Starbucks</CompanyName>
         <CreatedBy>example@example.com</CreatedBy>
      -</Company>
   </CompanyList>
</MainList>
```

Here is My Try i am getting every thing fine but   i am getting nothing in NSArray arr.

```
  NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"CompanyList"];  
  for (GDataXMLElement *icon in channels) {  
  NSArray *arr = [icon elementsForName:@"Company"];  
  if ([arr count]>0)  
  {  
        NSlog(@"Done");  
  }  
}
```

Comment: try allocating the nsarray object as NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];

Comment: and place a break point to check r u receiving data in chennels? if not then change your parsing technique

Comment: i did this but having no success

Comment: are u receving data in channels array?

Comment: Yes i am receiving data in Channels array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys i figured it out as follows

GDataXMLDocument    *xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];

```
NSLog(@"Error:%@",[error description]);

NSArray *getData = [[xmlDocument rootElement]elementsForName:@"CompanyList"];
NSArray  *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(GDataXMLElement *e in getData)
{

    NSArray *el = [e elementsForName:@"Company"];

    for (GDataXMLElement *e in el) {
        static int count =0;
        NSString    *testString = [[[e elementsForName:@"Address1"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Company  %d  : %@",count+1, testString);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer, this answer is helpful for u.  [NSXMLParser example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706056/932011)

Comment: i know about this but i am compelled on to do parsing with GDataXml ...for some reason.