# XMLParser iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I am creating a iPhone app' who needs to read a [XML file](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Pebkacfr?format=xml.xml)

### Properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fileName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *link;
```

---

### Search the tag (here only for the "title")

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    // FIRST TAG XML
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        // GET DATA FROM XML 
        getData = YES; // getData is a bool which is NO initialy
        NSLog(@"Found");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Not Found");

}
```

---

### Getting the data

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if(getData)
    {
        // CREATION DE L OBJET DEPUIS LE XML
        NSLog(@"This is your desired data = %@",string);
        NSLog(@"Object creation ...");
        Pebkac *peb = [[Pebkac alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Setup the name ...");
        [peb setName:@"Pebkac"];
        NSLog(@"Small descrption ...");
        [peb setDescription:string];
        [pebkacs addObject:peb];
    }
}
```

---

### End tag

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    // XML END TAG
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        getData = NO;
    }
}
```

---

The bug I've observed is that, sometimes it doesn't get the all text between tags.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example

Answer (score 6):

`foundChars` can be called N times. You always SET the string to the characters you get there. You gotta append the chars again and again and when you get the `endTag` call, THEN you have to set the result.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(!foundChars)
        foundChars = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [foundChars appendString:string];
}
```

then use it in the end -- **example is written to fit your question**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if(getData)
    {
        // CREATION DE L OBJET DEPUIS LE XML
        NSLog(@"This is your desired data = %@",string);
        NSLog(@"Object creation ...");
        Pebkac *peb = [[Pebkac alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Setup the name ...");
        [peb setName:@"Pebkac"];
        NSLog(@"Small descrption ...");
        [peb setDescription:foundChars];
        [pebkacs addObject:peb];
    }

    //reset
    foundChars = nil;

    // XML END TAG
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        getData = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 "foundChars can be called N times." That should be written in caps in the Apple's documentation.

Comment: **I don't understand everything can you show me exactly how to use it in didEndElement please ?**

Comment: edited the answer - foundChars has to be declared as a member variable

Comment: **But what's foundChars ? "Undeclared identifier" **

Comment: [foundChars appendString:string];
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'appendString'

Comment: As written it needs to be a member var: @interface myclass : naobject { nsmutablestring *foundChars;  } ...

Comment: member variable = instance variable

Answer (score 0):

### Method

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

May be called multiple times per element.  You need to append `string` together for each time this method is called per tag, and then set it on the object in:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
```

Reference this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example) for a concise example on how to properly accomplish use of `NSXMLParser`