# How to access XML data from SOAP web-service response in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, soap, nsxmlparser

I am using SOAP web service and in it I am able to read string response if web service return. But When web service return a string and an XML then I don't know how to access this XML response. For ex.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCountriesResponse xmlns="http://www.myurl.com/">
      <GetCountriesResult>
        <code>string</code>
        <profile>xmlxml</profile>
      </GetCountriesResult>
    </GetCountriesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

In it I don't know how to access these response of code and profile tag from XML. So can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example check this link

Comment: Best way to fetch data from web service is "TouchXML"

Answer (score 0):

See the SOAP Turorial at [SOAP Sample](https://github.com/ilteris/SOAPExample)
It may help you