# How to download, update and read an XML file within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am new to developing **iOS** apps and I wish to enable my app to download and read an XML file that will update each time the app is opened.

This is what I have so far:

```
NSURL * url = @"http://192.168.100.161/UploadWhiteB/wh.txt";
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if (data != nil) {
NSLog(@"\nis not nil");
NSString *readdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(NSData *)data ];
```

Comment: You have to post what you attempted to do so far. You cannot put a complex topic "in the open" and expect people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this code in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *localPath = [path objectAtIndex:0]; //The apps document directory

    NSString* fileURL = @"http://192.168.100.161/UploadWhiteB/wh.txt";
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];

    if (!(data==nil)) {
        [data writeToFile:[localPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wh.txt"] atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"Did download file: wh.txt");
    }
}
```

Then you can get the data by using this code in another class:

```
-(NSString *) getDocumentDirectory {
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [path objectAtIndex:0]; //The apps document directory
}

NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[self getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wh.txt"]];
if(!(xmlData==nil)) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method will run every time the app starts and download (and replace) the file **wh.txt** from your server to the file **wh.txt** on your device (in your apps document folder).

Then if you wan't to read the file you can use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html). See:

[How to Parse XML Files in Xcode](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad-App-Dev/a/How-To-Parse-Xml-Files-In-Xcode-Objective-C.htm) and
[NSXMLParser example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example)

Does it solve your problem?

If not, provide more information and I will edit my answer.